# Windows 8.1 Bluetooth disables after a while

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse, bluetooth

Since my Windows forcefully upgraded from 8 to 8.1 my Microsoft designer mouse stopped working properly. It's a Bluetooth Low Energy device.

It pairs well, works for some 3-7 minutes, and stops working. There are no errors or alerts. In the end, I need to keep the Settings App open at all times and re-enable it there every time it stops.

[Some places](http://www.techygeekshome.co.uk/2014/06/windows-81-bluetooth-issues-bluetooth.html) instruct in going to the Device Manager and disabling the option "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" on some hardware, under the "Power Management" tab.

What I did was I looked at every single device entry on Device Manager and unchecked all that had that option. Also I have updated all drivers I could.

My mouse still has the same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Bump. Anyone?
I hope I didn't waste money on this mouse.

Comment: I did endup upgrading to windows 10. After perfoming the procedure described in the question of deactivating "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" in some devices on Device manager it worked fine. Haven't had trouble since.